# How to compare 37 dichotomous variables (lab tests) to 31 dichotomous variables (diagnosis)

Tags: correlation, spss, matrix, bivariate

I've constructed a database based on chart review of patients. Patients had a variety of tests performed (37 different types, which were either positive, negative, or not performed aka 1/0/blank - I presume this is consistent with a dichotomous/nominal variable). A total of 31 possible diagnoses could have resulted, and I have encoded these as dichotomous variables (each diagnosis as 1/0 aka yes/no). (There were different tests that assessed for the same condition, hence 37>31).

Some collaborators have suggested creating a correlation matrix, which would doubly serve as input for data visualization. I am struggling with SPSS as to how best achieve this. In essence, I am unsure if Analyze>Correlate>Bivariate is the right path to take, or alternatively if a separate approach should be undertaken. For instance, certain tests were "clustered" together and I am not sure how to account for this occurrence. Further, I am not sure how to adjust for patient-level characteristics (which are not dichotomous variables, such as age, gender, and so on).

Thanks for your help in advance